# Node.js Cannot read property 'on' of undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, events, dom-events

What is wrong?

p.s. : I am new to node.js and I'm from .Net world!

My server.js code :

```
    var events = require('events').EventEmitter;
    var v = function() {
        var e = new events();
        e.emit('start');
    };

    var r = v();
    r.on('start', function(){
        console.log('event start just fired!!!!!!!!!!');
    });
```

and this console output :

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'on' of undefined
    at Object.<anonymous> (E:\Project\node\BasicSocial\server.js:12:2)
    at Module._compile (module.js:410:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:417:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:344:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:301:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:442:10)
    at startup (node.js:136:18)
    at node.js:966:3
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You forgot to return the event emitter from your `v` function:

```
var v = function() {
    var e = new events();
    e.emit('start');
    return e;
};
```

Also notice that the `start` event will not be called because you have emitted the event before you subscribed to it. So you could kind of rework your code a little:

```
var events = require('events').EventEmitter;
var v = function() {
    var e = new events();
    return e;
};

var r = v();
r.on('start', function(){
    console.log('event start just fired!!!!!!!!!!');
});

// emit the event after you have subscribed to the start callback
r.emit('start');
```

Comment: While that won't throw an error, the on("start") won't be triggered, since the event was already emitted when the on was binded.

Comment: so what is use of this event if so fast fired before we able to controlled?

Comment: It's not fast fired. It's fired when you (in your code) fire it explicitly using the `event()` function. So make sure you do so **after** you have subscribed to the event. So basically you have full control of what's happening. First you should make sure that the subscribers have been configured and then fire the event.

Comment: Oh,I see when i use r = v(); i fired my own event then i handled by my  .on event handler.

Comment: Yes, that was exactly one of the 2 problems with your original code.

Comment: so if i want to handle the start of an event how i can handled?

Comment: As you did, you subscribe to it: `r.on('start', ...` and then inside the anonymous callback handle the event (in your case you have logged some message to the console which is a good start).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102160/discussion-between-milad-and-darin-dimitrov).

Comment: sorry i ask so many Questions, but it not fired is this kind of problem has way and I saw some code use process.nextTick function and handle this kind of  problem what it is does?.

Answer (score 1):

`r` is undefined, since `v` isn't returning anything. That's why you're getting the error. And even if you return the event, your code won't give you the desired output, since you need to use `on("start")` before you use `emit("start")`

```
var events = require('events').EventEmitter;

var e = new events();

e.emit('start'); //This won't trigger the console.log

//Need to be binded before you emit the event.
e.on('start', function(){
    console.log('event start just fired!!!!!!!!!!');
});

e.emit('start'); //This will trigger the console.log
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `Process.nextTick()` or `setTimeout(yourFunction,0)`.

These two functions will come handy when you are emitting and using a callback function.

Here, using the `nextTick` function, I am able to push the function in the event loop which will be executed after all the processes in the call stack are executed i.e., in the end.

```
var EventEmitter = require('events').EventEmitter;

var getValue = function(val){
    var e = new EventEmitter();
    process.nextTick(function(){
        var c = 0;
        e.emit('Start');
        var t = setInterval(function(){
            e.emit('Processing data', ++c);
            if(c==val){
                e.emit('Stopped',c);
                clearInterval(t);

            }
        },10);

    });
    return e;
}

var r = getValue(7);

r.on('Start', function(){
    console.log("Started");
});

r.on('Processing data', function(d){
    console.log('Data '+d);
});

r.on('Stopped', function(d){
    console.log('Stopped '+d)
});
```

Comment: Please add more details buddy. OP says he's new to this. It would be a bit better if you gave some more insight into your proposed solution.

Comment: Added an example. :)

Answer (score 0):

You must forget to write new before making the event object

```
const events=require("events");
const event=***new*** events.EventEmitter();
event.on('click' ,() => console.log("hello"));
event.emit('click');
```